# Trying to make a histogram within python for number of magnitudes from a text file

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I need help on making a histogram dealing with the number of times a magnitude is within a range. I have a histogram made with the galaxy number, but I realized that doesn't really give any information.

I have tried making a bin of the galaxy numbers but realized that didn't really matter, nor did it work.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import math
from collections import Counter

import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit


histflux = []
galnum = []

with open('/home/jacob/PHOTOMETRY/PHOTOM_CATS/SpARCS-0035_totalall_HAWKIKs.cat', 'r') as magfile:
    magplots = csv.reader(magfile)
    firstmagline = magfile.readline()
    for line in magfile:
        id , ra , dec , x , y , hawkiks_tot , k_flag , k_star , k_fluxrad , totmask , hawkiks , ehawkiks , vimosu , evimosu , vimosb , \
        evimosb , vimosv , evimosv , vimosr , evimosr , vimosi , evimosi , decamz , edecamz , fourstarj1 , efourstarj1 , hawkij , ehawkij , \
        irac1 , eirac1 , irac2, eirac2 , irac3 , eirac3 , irac4 , eirac4 = line.split()

        goodflag = float(k_flag)
        goodhawki = float(hawkiks)

        if goodflag != 0.0:
            continue
        try:
            histfluxk = -2.5 * math.log10(goodhawki) +25
        except ValueError:
            print(histfluxk)

        histflux.append(histfluxk)
        galnum.append(float(id))

plt.hist([galnum, histflux])
plt.xlabel('Galaxy Number')
plt.ylabel('K-Band Magnitude')
plt.title('K-Band Magnitudes of Galaxies')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

What I want to see is a histogram with the x axis ranging from 0-20 flux magnitudes in intervals of 2. The y-axis should be the number of times that the flux magnitudes were within those ranges. I am stumped on how to do this because I am new to python and especially making graphs on python.

Comment: plt.hist(histflux,bins=list(range(0,22,2))) ?